# IF does not work when using variables

Tags: javascript

The second if does not work, and the third one does not work if I put a variable instead of "2" I was trying to put if (cont==len) but does not work. Which is the problem?

```
function alert(Vform){
var i=0;
var cont=0;
var len=Vform.length;
for (i=0;i<=len;i++){
    if (Vform.elements[i].checked!=true){
    cont=cont+1
    }
}
if (cont!=2){
    window.alert("Please select date and time");
}
```

}

Comment: I don't know if it results in a problem, but I wouldn't use `alert` as my own function name, because `alert` (even *without* window) is already a function part of the standard browser API. [(documentation)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert)

Comment: I am sure the if works perfectly fine; however your logic might not be working as you expect it to. I don't see a first if, but in what way isn't the logic of the second not working and what variable are you replacing the two with in the third.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do these changes:

```
function alert(Vform)
{
var cont=0;
var len=Vform.length;
for (var i=0;i<=len;i++)
{
    if (Vform.elements[i].checked!=true)
    {
        cont++;
    }
}
if (cont != 2)
{
    alert("Please select date and time");
}
}
```

Comment: I found out that the problem is at Vform.elements[i].checked

because if I replace the "i" for any number lower than 26(len) it works. I don't understand why

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop should be like this.

```
for (i=0;i<len;i++){
   //code
}
```

It should check `i<len` and not `i<=len` because array element start with zero based index